# Sitecore displaying Japanese even though language is set to English

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.5

Some elements of Sitecore have randomly started using Japanese. I have checked for the following issues:

- I have checked to make sure our Sitecore instance is set to English.
- I looked through the entire solution for references to `jp` but it doesn't seem that it is being hardcoded into anywhere.

This has been affecting the following:

- RTE's (the element selection menu e.g h1, h2, h3... is in Japanese)
- Our validation rules:

  [image]

Anyone had a similar issue.

This is on Sitecore 7.5.

---

**UPDATE 1**

I see that some items under `core/sitecore/system/Dictionary` have the `Phrase` field set to Japanese text. Could this have anything to do with it?

[image]

Comment: have you cleared your cookies? Language settings are often persisted through cookies in addition to the query string parameter or path. Alternatively see if the problem persists while in private browsing. Additionally you can check the core database to see if the English language version of the items that control whatever you're seeing in Japanese have been removed.

Comment: Private browsing did not make a difference. This issue occurs across computers as well so I don't think cookies would be it. I have been looking through the core database and noticed the following:

1. The RTE settings had some of their "Heading" fields set to Japanese. However, wiping this field still has it showing up in Japanese in the RTE.

2. Some items under core/sitecore/system/Dictionary have the "phrase" field set to Japanese. Is that of any significance?

Comment: Correction: Wiping the "Header" field DID fix the issue for the RTE. However, why would this be set to a Japanese phrase to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I'm assuming this was a bug in Sitecore but what happened is that all the Japanese translations in the core database's dictionary were moved to the English versions. This meant that it would translate to Japanese if it detected the mode was set to English.

Answer (score 0):

The user you're logging in with, what language preferences is set for it?

Is one thing that the Sitecore *site* runs in English, but a CMS editor user can still prefer to operate Sitecore in another language.

Control Panel => Region and Language settings